# How to share tileSets between different tiledMaps?

Tags: libgdx

If I have several .tmx files using the same tileSet, obviously I'd like to load the tileSet texture only once, but if I use the regular way to do it, the texture is loaded twice...

```
TmxMapLoader loader = new TmxMapLoader();

TiledMap tiledMap1 = loader.load("map-test.tmx");
TiledMap tiledMap2 = loader.load("map-test.tmx");

Texture texture1 = tiledMap1.getTileSets().getTile(1).getTextureRegion().getTexture();
Texture texture2 = tiledMap2.getTileSets().getTile(1).getTextureRegion().getTexture();

// texture1 is different than texture2
```

So my question is, is there any way to avoid the map loading the same assets several times?

Probably I'll end writing my own TmxLoader because I don't want it to load images from the Image layer but replace them with actual game objects... but I'd like to know the *vanilla* way...

**Edit:**
The solution provided by David Saltares was the one I needed, so I'll left here the proper code:

```
// supossing that both maps use the same tileset image...
TmxMapLoader loader = new TmxMapLoader();
assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, loader);
assetManager.load("map-test1.tmx", TiledMap.class);
assetManager.load("map-test2.tmx", TiledMap.class);

assetManager.finishLoading();
TiledMap tiledMap1 = assetManager.get("map-test1.tmx");
TiledMap tiledMap2 = assetManager.get("map-test2.tmx");

Texture texture1 = tiledMap1.getTileSets().getTile(1).getTextureRegion().getTexture();
Texture texture2 = tiledMap2.getTileSets().getTile(1).getTextureRegion().getTexture();
// now texture1 == texture2 :)
```

What I'm wondering is, why this is not the default? I mean, assetManager has lots of loaders by default, but not the tmx one...

Comment: You need to write your own loader.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl you actually don't, see answer below.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`AssetManager`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html), call its [`setLoader`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#setLoader-java.lang.Class-com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.AssetLoader-) method passing a new instance of [`TmxMapLoader`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TmxMapLoader.html).

When loading a map via the asset manager, the tmx loader will try to handle it and tell the asset manager all its dependencies. One of these dependencies will be the texture for the tiles. The asset manager will satisfy the dependencies and then the map will actually get loaded.

All assets under the manager are referenced counted, so calling `load()` on the same handle, won't actually allocate more memory.

This means that, when the second map gets loaded and the manager tries to satisfy its dependencies, it will find the texture is already loaded. It will simply increment its reference count by one.